# Android check null or empty string in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-fragmentactivity

In my trying `AsyncTask` I get email address from my server. In `onPostExecute()` I have to check is email address `empty` or `null`. I used following code to check it:

```
if (userEmail != null && !userEmail.isEmpty()) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), userEmail, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    UserEmailLabel.setText(userEmail);
}
```

But in my `Toast` I see `null` is printed. My full code:

```
private class LoadPersonalData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(String... res) {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", PrefUserName));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", type_data));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(Url, "POST", params);
        String result = "";
        try {
            result = json.getString("message");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (result.equals("success")) {
            try {
                userEmail = json.getString("email");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);            
        if (userEmail != null && !userEmail.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), userEmail, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            UserEmailLabel.setText(userEmail);
        }
    }
```

How can I check for `null` and `empty` string?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

From @Jon Skeet comment, really the `String` value is `"null"`. Following code solved it

```
if (userEmail != null && !userEmail.isEmpty() && !userEmail.equals("null"))
```

Comment: `if (userEmail != null && (!TextUtils.equals(userEmail ,"null")) && (!TextUtils.isEmpty(userEmail))){` also works

Comment: This may work for emails, but DON’T use `equals("null")` to check for a null username. http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20160325-the-names-that-break-computer-systems

Comment: It may perhaps be better to have `userEmail.equalsIgnoreCase("null")` in case of an uppercase null value.

Answer (score 179):

#### Use [`TextUtils.isEmpty( someString )`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence))

```java
String myString = null;

if (TextUtils.isEmpty(myString)) {
    return; // or break, continue, throw
}

// myString is neither null nor empty if this point is reached
Log.i("TAG", myString);
```

**Notes**

- The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence)) states that both null and zero length are checked for. No need to reinvent the wheel here.
- A good practice to follow is [early return](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/18473/186547).

Answer (score 31):

Yo can check it with this:

```
if(userEmail != null && !userEmail .isEmpty())
```

And remember you must use from exact above code with that order. Because that ensuring you will not get a null pointer exception from `userEmail.isEmpty()` if `userEmail` is null.

Above description, it's only available since Java SE 1.6. Check `userEmail.length() == 0` on previous versions.


**UPDATE:**

Use from `isEmpty(stringVal)` method from `TextUtils` class:

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userEmail))
```

**Kotlin:**

Use from `isNullOrEmpty` for null or empty values OR `isNullOrBlank` for null or empty or consists solely of whitespace characters.

```
if (userEmail.isNullOrEmpty())
...
if (userEmail.isNullOrBlank())
```

Answer (score 14):

**Checking for empty string if it is equal to null, length is zero or containing "null" string**

```
public static boolean isEmptyString(String text) {
        return (text == null || text.trim().equals("null") || text.trim()
                .length() <= 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can check it with utility method "isEmpty" from TextUtils,

isEmpty(CharSequence str) method check both condition, for null and length.

```
public static boolean isEmpty(CharSequence str) {
     if (str == null || str.length() == 0)
        return true;
     else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Right way to check empty string.**

**1.** It is faster but not null safe, it will throw NullPointErexception if string is null

```
if str.isEmpty() then
```

**2.** It is also faster but not null safe.

```
if String.length() = 0 then
```

**3.** It is not faster as previous two but it is null safe.

```
if "".equals(str) then
```

**4.** Fouth way

```
TextUtils.isEmpty(myString)
```

**5.** If you want to check for null string.

```
StringUtils.isEmpty(nullString)
```

**6.** If you want to check null and empty string both at same time

```
if (str == null || str.length() == 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

if you check null or empty String so you can try this

```
 if (yourString != null){
    if(yourString.length==0  && yourString.equals(""))
    Toast.makeText(myClassName.this, "Empty",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }else{
    Toast.makeText(myClassName.this, "String null" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

or using TextUtils class

```
 if (TextUtils.isEmpty(yourString )) {
       Toast.makeText(myClassName.this, "Empty" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If using Kotlin:-

```
 if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userEmail).not()) {
        // do your work
    } else {
        // can show error message userEmail is empty
    }
```

If using Java:-

```
  if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(userEmail)) {
        // do your work
    } else {
        // can show error message userEmail is empty
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

My simple solution to test if a string is null:

if (s.equals("null")){
  .....
}

There are two cases.

The variable (of type String) is null(doesn't exists):
== works.

The variable has a null value,
*.equals("null") gives te right boolean value.

See the picture.
[image]

Comment: Do you mean the word n-u-l-l or a variable with value null?

Answer (score 0):

Incase all the answer given does not work, kindly try

```
String myString = null;

if(myString.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("null")){
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

```
EditText   etname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etname);
 if(etname.length() == 0){
                    etname.setError("Required field");
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

or Use this for strings

```
String DEP_DATE;
if (DEP_DATE.equals("") || DEP_DATE.length() == 0 || DEP_DATE.isEmpty() || DEP_DATE == null){
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding a null check first.